# Replace all elements and redraw graph softly in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Is there any one-command way to replace all elements of my graph with new data in cytoscape.js?
In my case, after some operations on backend I have new graph-data and want to redraw my graph with this new data, but not to lose my camera settings, maybe something like

```
cy.elements = my_elements;
cy.redraw();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Options:

(1) `cy.elements().remove(); cy.add( newEleJsons );`

(2) `cy.json({ elements: newEleJsons });`